# Problems using the QGIS Db Manager and accessing a PostGIS file with a JSON field content to plot up JSON attribute content

Tags: qgis, postgis, json

[image: QGIS partial view of JSON content for post GIS file Screen Shot 2021-03-05 at 6.48.47 PM]

Using the QGIS (Madiera) Db Manager window and accessing a PostGIS file to try and plot up some of the JSON file content on to an existing QGIS basemap.  I am not a QGIS (or GIS) superuser!

I have used the SQL query in the DB Manager *select coordinates, json_record ->> 'monitor_location' as location from field_observations;*
to extract from a JSON field "*field_observations*".  This SQL query works, revealing the relevant attribute in the Db Manager viewer.

I then tried to use the “*Load as new layer*” feature to load the queried dataset, THIS NOW WORKS though there is no CRS assigned.  The preview works, though with the data appearing in an odd-ball place outside my NAD10UTM 40 project map space.

Any suggestions on what to do next to get a visible map?

Comment: can you give an example screenshot of the data format?

Comment: Tried to add an example of the data format for one of the PostGIS attributes (JSON) "field_observations" but not sure how to upload this to this Stack Exchange forum!

Comment: How to add a screen shot to my post on JSON?

Comment: edit question > image button (toolbar) add image.

Comment: Thank you I got the postGIS map display to work by unchecking "column with unique value".  The query results file now appears in the QGIS map window!, though now unable to view the map in my working QGIS (Madiera) CRS....